# Can not connect to SQL Server from Ubuntu sqlcmd client

Tags: sql-server, linux, connectivity, sqlcmd

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server Express server from a Linux Ubuntu 16.04 computer. I Installed all SQL commad line utilities for the linux machine and follow instructions from Microsoft SQL Server on Linux docs.

When I run

```
sqlcmd -S ip/SQLEXPRESS -U SA -P 1234
```

the command always returns the following error :

> Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
>   Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2AF9

I was able to run the same command from a Windows 10 computers and it works with no flaws.

The linux computer can communicate to the server machine and SQL Server 1433 port. I test this with the linux nc command (netcat).

Linux nc command results:

```
nc -z -v -w5 192.168.0.1 1433
```

> Connection to 192.168.0.1 1433 port [tcp/ms-sql-s] succeeded!

Any suggestions or something missing?

I have tried changing the ports, parameter order etc... and Linux version of `sqlcmd` doesn't work.

I also tried including extra '/' character, because it is special on Linux. The new command line is `sqlcmd -S ip//SQLEXPRESS -U SA -P 1234` but it doesn't work. It works faster but returns other error:

> Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746.

Instance name doesn't work neither. `sqlcmd -S SERVER-NAME\\SQLEXPRESS -U SA -P 1234` or `sqlcmd -H ipaddress -S SERVER-NAME\\SQLEXPRESS -U SA -P 1234` The command recognizes quotes so `sqlcmd -S "SERVER-NAME\SQLEXPRESS" -U SA -P 1234`. Nothing works.

The correct syntax is `sqlcmd -S ip\\SQLEXPRESS -U SA -P 1234` with double '\'. It doesn't connect anyway. I have several days struggling with it and could not find a way to make this thing work.

Comment: You may want to try these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57453901/6598234

Answer (score 1):

I think the right command should be:

```
sqlcmd -S <IP>\\SQLEXPRESS,1433 -U SA
```